# Quelle est l'origine du mot « Sorbonne » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, étymologie

Je voudrais connaître l'étymologie du mot *Sorbonne*. D'où vient-il ?

Notez que c'est la première question que je pose en français. Naturellement, j'en suis un petit peu nerveux.

Comment: Félicitations pour la barre des 500 rep, et pour la première question en français! :)

Comment: Question très bien posée, il n'y a pas de quoi être nerveux :)

Comment: Merci à tous. C'est très gentil à vous de me dire que ma question a été bien posée.

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez Why _connaître_? It's about knowing information, not people, like in the link you've given me yourself.

Comment: Yeah, but it's more subtle than that, some pieces of information are considered substantial rather than factual. In some way you also want to “meet them”, like people.

Comment: Malgré la science indiscutable de Stéphane Gimenez, je me permets de critiquer ... sa critique de l'utilisation de "connaître" ; il faut voir tous les exemples des auteurs classiques : on peut connaître une information, connaître le français (je ne dis pas : le Français) - j'admets que c'est maintenant moins usuel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si tu fais référence au bâtiment, il tire son nom de Robert de Sorbon, comme l'indique [Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorbonne).

J'ai découvert que c'était aussi un nom commun, désignant une [hotte dans un laboratoire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sorbonne), et il partage la même étymologie.

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour votre réponse. Y-a-t-il des erreurs dans ma question?

Comment: _Une hotte_, c'est-à-dire _a sack_ or _a hood_?

Comment: Dans le sens de *fume hood*. Et en dehors des deux petites corrections que j'y ai apportées, la question est nickel!

Comment: Vraiment? Super!