# Y a-t-il une expression plus argotique pour « être bon en quelque chose » ?

Tags: expressions, argot, registre-familier

Je voudrais savoir s'il y a une expression plus argotique pour dire : *être bon(ne) en quelque chose*. Quelque chose similaire aux expressions anglaises *to be deft at something* ou *to be a dab at / in*.

Comme dans le roman *La Maison d'Âpre-Vent* de Charles Dickens :

> My friend is a regular dab at it.

Comment: You are all confusing me. I  wrote _savoir_, but _Zistoloen_ edited it to _connaître_. So which one is it: _je voudrais savoir_ or _je voudrais connaître_? Also, the same _Zistoloen_ edited my _j'en suis ... nerveux_ to the simpler _je suis ... nerveux_? Wasn't it correct the way I first wrote it? Doesn't _j'en suis nerveux_ mean _I'm nervous about it_? If it does, why did he / she edit it? Please shed some light on it!

Comment: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/39/connaitre-and-savoir

Comment: @Zistoloen I originally wrote _savoir_. Then you edited it to _connaître_. 4 mins ago you edited it back to _savoir_. Can you please decide which one it is? You are truly confusing me. Je ne suis pas bon en français. I'm just a beginner in French. So, please, don't mess with my mind.

Comment: @indoxica: pour cette question, _savoir_ convient très bien. C'est pour ton [autre question](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6915/quelle-est-lorigine-du-mot-sorbonne) que j'avais précisé que _connaître_ était plus approprié.

Comment: @Zistoloen Not true. Please check the edit log. You will see that I originally wrote _savoir_. Please do check the edit log.

Comment: @indoxica: Regarde les logs de cette question et tu verras que ce n'est pas moi qui ait édité ta question pour changer le mot _connaître_ en _savoir_.

Comment: @Zistoloen As to my other question (http://french.stackexchange.com/posts/6915/revisions), you will plainly see who changed my original _savoir_ to _connaître_.

Comment: @indoxica: ok on dit la même chose, ce n'est pas grave. L'important c'est que tes deux questions utilisent les bons termes à présent.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Je ne connais pas le niveau de langue de l'expression anglaise, mais des équivalents familiers, sans être vraiment argotiques, de *être bon en* seraient

- assurer en
- gérer en
- toucher en

Il y a aussi tous les synonymes de *bon*

- être balaise/balèze en
- être fortiche en

Et puis dans la veine de la [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/6919/1129) fournie Swiss12000

- être une brute en
- être un crack en

Comment: *Il assure en anglais*, d'accord, mais les autres ne fonctionnent pas. Il faudrait dire *il touche **sa bille** en anglais*, mais cette expression a un peu vieilli

Comment: Peut-être une question de région ou de génération, mais j'entends et j'utilise par exemple *tu gères en anglais* ou *il touche en board*.

Comment: Synonyme de _toucher (sa bille)_, il y a aussi _tâter_.

Answer (score 7):

J'utiliserais l'expression:

- C'est une tuerie en ...

Par exemple en parlant d'une personne bonne en informatique:

- C'est une tuerie en informatique.

Sinon on pourrait aussi dire "C'est une bête en..."

Comment: L'expression _être une bête en_ est très drôle.

Comment: *C'est une brute en...* se dit aussi

Answer (score 7):

- C'est un cador en
- C'est un dieu en
- Il se promène/balade en
- Il fait ça les doigts dans le nez

Answer (score 7):

Il existe aussi toutes les expressions à partir de **grave**, déjà mentionnées dans un commentaire de *olibre*, mais qui méritent plus qu'un commentaire je pense.

Dernier exemple remarquable authentique culture française : [Nabilla a "assuré grave" au défilé, selon Jean-Paul Gaultier](http://lci.tf1.fr/people/nabilla-a-assure-grave-au-defile-selon-jean-paul-gaultier-8096549.html)

Il s'agit d'apposer *grave* à la mention de compétence pour que ça devienne de l'argot : *il réfléchit grave*.

Il y a *il maîtrise grave* déjà donné dans le commentaire, mais en veux-tu en voilà *il assure grave*, *il kiffe grave*, *il adhère grave*, *il morfle grave*, **il [ce que vous voulez] grave**.

Comment: « Grave » est synonyme de « beaucoup » ici, et n'implique aucune compétence particulière, hein. La seule partie de la réponse qui correspond à la question ici, c'est « assurer grave », mais le mot important est « assurer », pas l'autre.

Comment: C'est ce que je dis, non ?... : _Il s'agit d'apposer grave à la mention de compétence pour que ça devienne de l'argot_. Grave n'est pas seulement un synonyme de beaucoup, mais il change le registre de la langue, la faisant passer à l'argot. Si je dis "Nabilla assure", je parle correct ; si je dis "Nabilla assure grave" ça veut peut être dire "Nabilla assure beaucoup", mais ça veut surtout dire que, plein de l'émoi provoqué par les compétences de Nabilla, j'en arrive à parler argot, montrant par là que c'est le comble du comble. Et si je dis "Nabilla assure beaucoup"... personne ne m'écoute.

Answer (score 5):

Le terme *maîtriser* dans le sens *être bon* s'utilise à la fois dans le registre soutenu et dans le registre familier. Ici un exemple dans le registre familier :

> T'**es** vachement **bon** en surf !
>
> Tu **maîtrises** à donf le surf !

Comment: Ma compréhension de la question d'indoxica est qu'il cherche des expressions du registre familier/argotique.

Comment: Salut @Shlublu. C'est justement ce que j'entends de la part des jeunes pour dire qu'un ami **est bon**: *il **maîtrise** tel truc*, et même *il **maîtrise** grave tel truc*. Cependant, je te l'accorde, c'est une expression qui peut aussi être utilisée dans un contexte plus sobre, bien loin du registre familier/argotique... Donc, après réflexion, ma proposition n'est pas spécifiquement familière/argotique. Merci pour ta remarque ;-)

Comment: En fait, je n'avais jamais remarqué ce double registre ! Pourtant, une fois mis en évidence, c'est limpide. C'est bien d'en avoir parlé :)

Answer (score 5):

Dans ce cas précis, pour conserver le côté surranné, je dirais « c'est un as » ou « c'est un chef ». Pour préciser que c'est le meilleur, on a dans la même veine  « c'est le patron ».

Answer (score 3):

Et juste pour compléter cette belle liste:

- *Déchirer* (ou *tout déchirer*, ou encore *déchirer grave*, etc...)

> "*Ce mec **déchire (tout)** en surf !*" => "*Quel excellent surfeur que cet homme !*"

- *Etre au taquet*

> "*Cherche pas, **je suis au taquet** en technique de saut à ski !*" => "*Inutile de s'interroger plus avant, ma maîtrise des techniques de saut à ski est parfaite*"

- *Etre un boss*

> "*Ouah ! **Tu es un boss**, mec !*" => "*Mon ami, ton talent force mon admiration.*"

Il en existe encore bien d'autres.